# Successful summing objects with dictionaries from the same class / It works, but looking for an explanation

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I'm looking for help from good people

Why the .copy() has to be inside the __add__ method ? It doesn't work without it.

```
class Traveler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {}

    def add(self, item):
        self.inventory[item.lower()] = self.inventory.setdefault(item.lower(), 0) + 1

    def __add__(self, *backpacks):
        total = self.inventory.copy() # total = self.inventory ?
        for back in backpacks:
            for item in back.inventory:
                total[item] = total.setdefault(item, 0) + back.inventory[item]
        return total

backpack = Traveler()
backpack_2 = Traveler()
backpack.add('flashlight')
backpack.add('water')
backpack.add('food')
backpack.add('knife')

backpack_2.add('flashlight')
backpack_2.add('water')
backpack_2.add('knife')
backpack_2.add('food')

all_items = backpack + backpack_2

print(f"backpack = {backpack.inventory}")
print(f"backpack 2 = {backpack_2.inventory}")
print(f'All items {all_items}')
```

Correct output with the .copy() function:

```
backpack = {'flashlight': 1, 'water': 1, 'food': 1, 'knife': 1}
backpack 2 = {'flashlight': 1, 'water': 1, 'knife': 1, 'food': 1}
All items {'flashlight': 2, 'water': 2, 'food': 2, 'knife': 2}
```

Incorrect output without this function:

```
backpack = {'flashlight': 2, 'water': 2, 'food': 2, 'knife': 2} # Why it is doubled ?
backpack 2 = {'flashlight': 1, 'water': 1, 'knife': 1, 'food': 1}
All items {'flashlight': 2, 'water': 2, 'food': 2, 'knife': 2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python when you assign an object (in your case a dictionary) to a variable using the "`=`" operator **it took the reference**, not a copy of it.

So when you doing `total = self.inventory`, `total` and `self.inventory` **are literally the same object**.

Doing `self.inventory.copy()` you **create a new object** so all works as expected.

Comment: Very quick and clear explanation, thank you so much. Are these references useful somewhere ? They can be a little bit confusing sometimes.

Comment: References are fundamental for **performance reasons**: imagine to copy a long
list/dictionary/whatever every time you passing it to a function that doesn't
change it. That would take a lot of useless cpu and memory resources, but with
a reference you can access directly to the resource.
To avoid confusion I suggest you 2 things:
 keep in mind that **in Python every variable is a reference** and
 avoid to copy, generate a new object instead: for example, in your code, try
to do `total = {}`.
Btw thanks a lot for the compliment :)